# Pick a certain axis from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of size (100, 2, 15, 27) (these are 100 images, with 2 channels of size 15x27). I want to separate the 2 channels in order to get 2 separate arrays of size (100, 1, 15, 27) (I do need that 1 there). How can I do that? I usually pick column using a[:,i], but this higher dimensionality confuses me. Thank you!

Comment: `a[:, [0]]` or `a[:, [0],:,:]` will give you a (100,1,15,27).  The trailing `:` are optional.  The `[0]` preserves that dimension.  `a[:, 0]` gives a (100,15,27).  I like to make a smaller array, e.g. `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` and experiment.  That way it's easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`a[:,i]` works again. If you need to, you can add dimensions with `.reshape(100,1,15,27)` or a nicer way, `np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `moveaxis` then separate them as you want:

```
x = np.moveaxis(x, 1, 0)
x.shape
# (2, 100, 15, 27)
first_chanel = x[0]
second_chanel = x[0]
```